# Get previously saved value from state, after component re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating an event management client server application where the admin panel provides functionality to modify an existing module.

when the user click on the edit button with accordance to the module info shown in a table, a unique module ID is passed to the editModuleForm() for the sake to modify the module in the database.

The problem is I'm getting an undefined value the Module ID passed when the edit component render for some reason. The component only have to render when the user click on the edit button and remove when cross button on .

[image: Screenshot]

This is the state I'm managing, the edit panel toggles b/w true or false managed in the state.

```
this.state = {
  editModuleDisplay: false,
}
```

in the edit button code to toggle state and passing the module id

```
<i className="fa fa-pencil text-warning padding-left-lg iconStyles"
    onClick={ async () => {
        await this.editModuleForm(props.original.m_id)
        await this.setState({
            editModuleDisplay: true
        })
    }}
/>
```

in editModuleForm()

```
editModuleForm = (id) => {
    console.log(id)  //logging the module id
return ( some JSX form )
}
```

in render()

```
 {this.state.editModuleDisplay && this.editModuleForm()}
```

I want to have the module ID in the edit form so when the user modify a module, I can modify the module by that unique module ID in the database.

Quick Note: I am no familiar with Redux, so if Redux is somewhat helpful, please brief.

Comment: tons of todo tutorials with the same schema - search first

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have displayed you are trying to make an asynchronous call to a function and not a promise. editform is not a Promise so you can't await it. If you are trying to share state you need to either pass it down from parent component,  use the Context api, or Redux depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the form id in react state itself and pass down accordingly:

```
editModuleForm = (id) => {
  this.setState({
   editingFormId:id
  })
    console.log(id)  //logging the module id
  return ( some JSX form )
}
```